# How to assign product image from gallery to product Magento

Tags: jquery, image, magento, product, assign

Hi i have a database of around 25000 products. There are so many products which have there gallery images but they are not assigned to product
Can you please tell me what shoyuld be the query which check if the product dont have thumbnail or base image but have gallery image and to assign them.

I have try to find the products with the following code

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('neq'=>'no_selection'));
```

but the problem is the product has images in gallery but not assign .
So please tell me how can i find product with gallery image and assigned that to product.

Answer (score 0):

I have set first  product gallery image to small image.

```
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('neq'=>'no_selection'));

    foreach($products as $pro){

    $product->load($pro->getId());
    $gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    $paths = array();
    foreach ($gallery as $image) {
        $paths[] = $image->getFile();
       $product->setSmallImage($image->getFile())
            ->save();
break;
    }

    }
```